# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Bitmap.copy function

Tags: java, android, bitmap

> I thought there is two copies of same object.that may be the issue.but I do not know how to solve that.please help me.Thanks in advance

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
// I got error in this line.
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }
```

> logcat

```
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCopy(Native Method)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.java:403)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rajitha.myapplication.RoundedImageView.onDraw(RoundedImageView.java:39)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11054)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10493)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2958)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2596)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10491)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2958)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2596)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.example.rajitha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11057)
10-18 11:04:33.208 32110-32110/com.e
```

Comment: Have you read http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2):

**`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:`** **Requested size exceeds VM limit.**
This error indicates that a Java application attempts ti allocate an array, whose size is larger than the heap size.

**The OutOfMemoryError extends the VirtualMachineError** class, which indicates that the JVM is broken, or it has run out of resources and cannot operate.

> Verify that your application does not store unnecessary information.
>   Store and maintain only those pieces of information required for the
>   proper execution of your Java application.

Please Read Below Document

1. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
2. [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)